# How to use dependency injection in JAXB unmarshalled objects?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jaxb, cdi

I have a factory class

```
@ApplicationScoped /* 'ApplicationScoped' is not a must */
class MyFactory {

   @Inject
   private IService aService;

   ...
}
```

And an JAXB annotated class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "item")
class AnItem {

  @Inject
  MyFactory myFactory;

  ...
}
```

`AnItem` is instantiated by JAXB from an XML file.
The problem is that `myFactory` is `null`. If I replace this by

```
...
MyFactory myFactory = new MyFactory();
...
```

then `myFactory.aService` is null.

How can I use dependency injection within classes created by JAXB?

Comment: Are you using spring? If you are you can do constructor based wiring with aspectj.

Comment: unfortunately not. I have to use Glassfish...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution is inspired by a [Block of Adam Warski](http://www.warski.org/blog/2010/10/di-and-oo-assisted-inject-in-cdi-weld/), see also [BeanManager Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html)

At first I'll need two utility methods:

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class Utils {
  public static BeanManager getBeanManager() {
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        return (BeanManager) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to retrieve BeanManager!", e);
    }
  }

  public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> c) {
    T result = null;
    BeanManager bm = getBeanManager();
    Set<Bean<?>> beans = bm.getBeans(c);
    if (! beans.isEmpty()) {
        Bean<?> bean = beans.iterator().next();
        result = c.cast(bm.getReference(bean, c, bm.createCreationalContext(bean)));
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Class `AnItem` has then to be changed like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "item")
class AnItem {

  MyFactory myFactory = Utils.getBean(MyFactory.class);

  ...
}
```

Comment: That's certainly one way to do it. Look at DeltaSpike, we have that all taken care of in the BeanProvider class.

Comment: DeltaSpike? Never heard about it. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some code in the wrong class, which is causing dependencies to be around the wrong way, which in turn makes the objects difficult to construct correctly.

`Item` looks like a *newable* class (sometimes known as an entity).  Newable classes are not created by your container, but are created by *service* classes.  Jaxb is an example of a service.  The service classes are created by your DI container.

I would re-evaluate your need to have `Item` hold a reference to `myFactory`.  You have not shown this in your question, but there must be a method in `Item` that makes a call to something in `myFactory`.

This code should be moved out of `Item` into a different class (perhaps a new service) that accepts an `item` as a parameter.

Comment: well I could post the whole project but this is not the point. 
This is just a (maybe stupid) example. But my question is clear: how can classes instantiate by JAXB enjoy the benefits of CDI? But I didn't ask "how can I refactor my project?"

Comment: I admit I'm not really asking the question as asked and there is not sufficient information to know if I'm right, but thought it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

CDI beans are supposed to be container managed, meaning if you use `new` to create them you don't get any of the container services (injection, interception, decorators, etc). You'd need to `@Inject` your factory class to have the injection work correctly.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. Actually this is the problem that classes created by JAXB are not managed by default. I hoped that there is a way to let JAXB work together with CDI since both are part of javee.

Comment: That would require an update to the JAXB specification. I strongly recommend you find and contact the spec lead / maintenance lead for JAXB and request this.